# AnyLogic: Change source "Arrivals defined by" at runtime

Tags: anylogic

Topic is related to Process Modeling Library, Source. Objective is to change between "Rate" and "Interarrival time" for Source during the simulation.

Switching to "Rate" during the simulation works fine. When switching to "Interarrival time" I face problems - I cannot seem to control the interarrival time with the set_rate function. I've even tried to hardcode the arrival rate (commented in code) - but that did not work either. Any suggestions?

```
if (comboArrival.getValueIndex()==0)
    {
    source.set_arrivalType(sourceRate.INTERARRIVAL_TIME);
    source.set_rate(arrivalRate/60, PER_MINUTE);
    //source.set_rate(1.0, PER_MINUTE);
    }
else
    {
    source.set_arrivalType(sourceRate.RATE);
    source.set_rate(arrivalRate/60/60);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The interarrival time is dynamic. You can simply put a variable in its field and change the variable.

[image]

Now all you need to do is change `variable` e.g.

```
variable = arrivalRate/60, PER_MINUTE;
```

Of course you would still need to change the arrival type to interarrival time as you are already doing before changing the variable value.

Comment: Thanks. I am still unable to get it to work - the issue appears whenever I switch from Rate to Interarrival time.  I am using your approach as follows:
`if (comboArrival.getValueIndex()==0)
{
source.set_arrivalType(sourceRate.INTERARRIVAL_TIME);
variable=arrivalRate/60;
//variable=1.0; //I tried 5.0, 1.0, 0.1, 0.01 all without effect
}
else
{
source.set_arrivalType(sourceRate.RATE);
source.set_rate(arrivalRate/60/60);
}`
I also tried to set the variable BEFORE changing to Interarrival time -no success. Any ideas?

Comment: I apologies for the formatting above - I could not get it to show in a reasonable format.

Comment: I tried your exact same setup and it's working... I wonder what we're doing different. I will send you a link to the model I am using.

Comment: Also, when you say "no success", what exactly is going wrong? Could it be unexpected behavior due to inconsistent units?

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f64cea5d99bb8f61dd2e4c49f524d2b420220626172542/cf1c60

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the Properties for Source - I had to make sure that the "Interarrival Time" was selected first. Switching from Interarrival time to Rate dynamically worked. When I tried to set up the Properties for Source as Rate and then switch dynamically to Interarrival time, I kept facing problems.

Comment: So you're saying `set_rate` worked for the interarrival time?